# Could not find or load main class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, kotlin, aws-lambda

I'm getting this error when trying to invoke the AWS Lambda of a Kotlin project that I've dockerized

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda`

This is what my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM gradle:6.7.1 as builder

# Copy sourcecode into build image
COPY app/build.gradle ./app/
COPY app/src/ ./app/src/
COPY settings.gradle ./
COPY gradle.properties ./


ENV ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_USR=[redacted]
ENV ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_PSW=[redacted]

RUN gradle clean build --no-daemon --stacktrace

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk13:debianslim-jre
# Put the one necessary class files, with all dependencies, into the into the runtime.

COPY --from=builder ./home/gradle/app/build/libs/app.jar .
COPY --from=builder ./home/gradle/app/build/libs/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/libs
COPY --from=builder ./home/gradle/app/build/classes/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY --from=builder ./home/gradle/app/build/libs/app.jar ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}



ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-cp", "./*", "com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda" ]

CMD ["readCartMessageDBLambda.App::handleRequest"]
```

This is what I've managed to put together using various Kotlin examples online. I haven't been able to find a ton of resources on how to do this. I just simply want to take my Kotlin project, and invoke it via AWS Lambda. I have `RequestHandler` implemented already. Also, I do have this in the dependencies of my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client:1.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Java V1 API to write Kotlin code. Have you looked at the brand new **AWS SDK for Kotlin**? Its still very new - but works. See the Kotlin Lambda examples here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/.kotlin_alpha/services/lambda

Now having said that - I am not aware of anyone trying to run these examples from a  docker environment.